# Type instantiation and declaration on the same line

Tags: java, object, types, instance, instantiation

So I just had an argument with a friend about efficiently instantiating and declaring variables in Java; that argument ended in a stalemate, as neither of us could make a point that could not be equally fought, all of which summed to a matter of opinion. However, my questions are:

If I declare say 3 variables on the same line: `Object x,y,z;`, it is the same as declaring them on three separate lines: `Object x;` `Object y;` `Object z;`. However, is it more efficient to declare them all on one line?

If I declare 3 variables on the same line and instantiate them all simultaneously, are they all bound to the same Object/Value?: `Object x,y,z = new Object();` Or is x equal to a new instance of type `Object` as well as `y` and `z` equal to new instances of `Object`?

If I declare 3 variables on the same line and instantiate them all individually rather than do so on 3 separate lines, is it more efficient, or just a matter of opinion?:

```
Object x = new Object(),y = new Object(),z = new Object();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, is it more efficient to declare them all on one line?

Nothing change, both are same, except readability counts.

> If I declare 3 variables on the same line and instantiate them all
>   simultaneously, are they all bound to the same Object/Value?:

No only `z` will be initialized. x and y will be `null` if they are class level variables.

> If I declare 3 variables on the same line and instantiate them all
>   individually rather than do so on 3 separate lines, is it more
>   efficient, or just a matter of opinion?:

No, it's not different than instantiating them separately.

However, to bring the topic to different direction, main point of this kind of declaration is based on the *readability* and *convention* on which all the other programmers should agree.

Read this first,

```
Object o1,o2,o3 = new Object(),o4,o5,o6,o8;
```

and now this,

```
Object o1;
Object o2;
Object o3 = new Object();
Object o4;
Object o5;
Object o6;
Object o8;
```

in which case you have first realized that `o7` is missing and `o3` is initialized. May be in both cases for some people, but consider this declaration is part of huge project and you have these kind of declarations in many places. Now, this both declarations can make difference.

Comment: So then it just comes down to a matter of opinion, and readability.

Answer (score 1):

1. Declaring `Object x, y, z` and `Object x; Object y; Object z;` is absolutely the same from the efficiency point of view. Even in Java bytecode these two cases are not distinguished.
2. When you declare `Object x,y,z = new Object();`, you assign only `z` variable. The `x` and `y` are still uninitialized.
3. Declaring several variables on the same line is absolutely the same as declaring them on separate lines from the efficiency point of view. Even in Java bytecode these two cases are not distinguished.